# MongoServerError: Invalid Namespace in Node.js App Using Mongoose with MongoDB Atlas

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm developing a Node.js twitter-like application where I use Mongoose (version 8.0.2) to interact with a MongoDB Atlas database. However, I've encountered an error saying `MongoServerError: Invalid namespace specified 'Twitter/.users'`. This issue arises when I try to perform operations using my Mongoose models.

Here's a brief overview of my setup:

1. Mongoose User Model

```
 const mongoose = require('mongoose');

   const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
       username: String,
       password: String,
       email: String,
       registerDate: Date
   });

   module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

2. Database Connection
   I'm using the following connection string to connect to MongoDB Atlas:

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://[username]:[password]@[cluster].mongodb.net/Twitter/?retryWrites=true&w=majority", { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
```

Despite following the standard practices, I'm getting the mentioned error. It's puzzling because there's no direct reference to .users in my code.

I've tried the following without success:

1. Ensuring the database name is correct in the Atlas console.
2. Double-checking the collection names and model definitions.
3. Searching my entire codebase for any accidental references to .users.

I suspect it might be related to how Mongoose interacts with MongoDB Atlas, but I'm not sure what exactly is causing this issue or how to resolve it.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or can suggest what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you have a trailing forward slash after your `Twitter` database name here:

```js
mongodb.net/Twitter/?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

Simply change your connection string to remove that forward slash:

```js
mongodb.net/Twitter?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

Comment: This one should be the accepted answer.